# Simplify a SQL table result with less rows

Tags: pivot

I have a table where there are some names with 3 sports. If the person practices the sport it shows a '1' else '0'.

[image]

How can I change the table with SQL so that it only shows a line per person, like this:

[image]

Regrads,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is referred to as an aggregate query.  See the [MySQL dev page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) for details about the various aggregates you can use.

This query will return a sum total for each sport, for each `Name`.

```
SELECT Name
    , SUM(Football) AS Football
    , SUM(Darts) AS Darts
    , SUM(Diving) AS Diving
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Name;
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa5f82/2/0) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL, supports a [`bool_or`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) for this, (`SUM` also works, but it's slower)

```
CREATE TABLE foo(name,darts,nakedtwister)
AS VALUES
  ('Evan',  false, true),
  ('Jane',  false, true),
  ('Andrew',true,  false),
  ('Mary',  true,  true);

SELECT name,
  bool_or(darts) AS darts,
  bool_or(nakedtwister) AS fun,
  'NOT A REAL SPORT' AS "golf/terrorism"
FROM foo
GROUP BY name;
```